# Filter containing a word

Tags: r

I have created a column of paths on R that looks like this:

```
Path
Adam > Bob > Jeff
Bob > Sarah > Kevin
Adam > Sarah > Kevin
Jeff > Adam > Bob
Adam > Kevin > Jeff
```

How do I filter the column, so It just has the paths involving Jeff:

```
Path
Adam > Bob > Jeff
Jeff > Adam > Bob
Adam > Kevin > Jeff
```

Comment: Try `df1[grep("\\bJeff\\b", df1$Path, ignore.case = TRUE),, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: Do you care to differentiate "Jeff" from "Jefferson"?

Comment: Awesome Dude, Thanks alot

Comment: I was trying to use filter but that didnt work, Akrun solved it, so dont worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` either using `[` (For `[`, by default `drop = TRUE` - therefore, we need to change it to `drop = FALSE` to avoid the one column/one row datasets converted to `vector`)

```
df1[grep("\\bJeff\\b", df1$Path, ignore.case = TRUE),, drop = FALSE]
```

or with `subset`, we don't have to use the `drop = FALSE` as it is by default `FALSE`

```
subset(df1, grepl("\\bJeff\\b", Path, ignore.case = TRUE))
#                 Path
#1   Adam > Bob > Jeff
#4   Jeff > Adam > Bob
#5 Adam > Kevin > Jeff
```

The pattern we match would be "Jeff", but to make it more stringent i.e. not to match "Jeffy" or "Jefferson", we can add the word boundary (`\\b`) before and after the word.